# The if statement not working properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a logic that if anyone enters `"<p>" and "</p>"` characters inside `<textarea>`, then only Jquery should show the win message.I have a `textarea` with class `html`, a `h2` with class `result` which shows win or loss.By now, I have this code:

```
var html = $('.html').val();
if(html.indexOf("</p>" && "<p>") === -1)
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You lost it.";
}
else{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hurray!You won";
}
```

But, this code is only checking if the `<p>` is there and not checking for `</p>`.So what can I do....

Comment: `html.indexOf("</p>" && "<p>")` - is that valid to have `&& <expr>` inside `indexOf`?

Comment: `"</p>" && "<p>" === "<p>"`, you'll need to check both and then compare results.

Comment: @tymeJV Yes it is, as long as the result of expression(s) can be evaluated to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `"</p>" && "<p>"` is equivalent to `"<p>"` -- `&&` evaluates each of its arguments from left to right, and returns the last truthy argument. Since both strings are truthy, what you wrote is effectively:

```
if (html.indexOf("<p>") === -1)
```

If you want to test whether a string contains two substrings, you have to call `indexOf` separately for each of them:

```
if (html.index("</p>") !== -1 && html.indexOf("<p>") !== -1)
```

Comment: oh @Barmar.I can't get the way to thnx you more than saying it you here.Thnq very much.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN (Logical Operators) - Logical And (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

`</p>` isn't being evaluated as false, so the second value is returned which is `<p>`.

This means that you're only checking for the index of `<p>`. Try this instead:

```
var html = $('.html').val();
if (html.indexOf("</p>") === -1 && html.indexOf("<p>") === -1) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You lost it.";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hurray! You won";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.indexOf` takes a single string as an argument. You cannot combine string elements together using `&&` like that.

The *simplest* way to modify your code would be to make two separate checks, one for the opening tag and one for the close:

```
if (html.indexOf("</p>") !== -1 && html.indexOf("<p>") !== -1)
```

This makes two separate checks for the two strings.

Alternatively, you could create a jQuery object from the HTML fragment inside your `<textarea>`, then check that it has no children that are `<p>` tags:

```
if ($('<div>'+html+'</div>').find('p').length > 0) {
    // the textarea contains some <p> tags
}
```